# Сравнить значение из базы с массивом?

Tags: php, база-данных

В PHP мы имеем право делать так?

```
SELECT text FROM whatdoing WHERE id !='$whatwas' ORDER BY RAND()
```

При том, что $whatwas-массив со всеми id,которые уже были.

Надо:
В БД есть таблица с "текст/id/цена(вес текста)" и таблица с игроками, у которых есть ячейка whatwas, где идёт перечисление всех id текстов, которые уже видел игрок (они записаны в ячейку примерно так "0||5||7", потом я их получаю и через explode преобразую в массив $whatwas). цель - выбирать из таблицы с текстами только те тексты, которые игрок ещё не видел.

Если не будет работать условие, которое я описал в начале, то подскажите/помогите как реализовать задуманное.

Comment: `WHERE ID NOT IN ()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'...WHERE ID NOT IN('.join(',', $whatwas).')...'
```

Comment: спасибо большое, вроде работает. З.Ы.после IN( должны быть двойные кавычки. А то я уже паниковать начал, мол как это не работает :D Ещё не могли бы вы объяснить/скинуть мануал про .join и чем он отличается от .implode?

Comment: 1) Какие ещё двойные кавычки, зачем? `NOT IN(1,2,3,4)` вполне достаточно 2) Ничем. А употребляю я join вместо implode потому, что это семантически естественная конструкция,  делающая одно и то же в разных языках от SQL до хаскеля, и с какого в PHP решили выпендриться и пойти своим путём - непонятно. Мне проще  "не сбивать руку", чем помнить, что вот в этом частном случае всё не как у людей :)

Comment: @u_mulder так информация плохо усваивается. Я предпочитаю диалоги, сухой информации. Вот уважаемы klopp ответил и обогатил мои знания, когда вы мягко говоря меня послали... в гугл. Но вам, кстати, тоже спасибо. Была бы возможность поставить + комменту, я бы поставил. Однако я совсем новичок и совсем не понял как с этим работать.

Comment: @klopp 1) `NOT IN(".join(',', $whatwas).")` так работает, а так `NOT IN('.join(',', $whatwas).')` - нет. 2) Хм, спасибо. Заметил, что у PHP достаточно похожих случаев. У JS тоже... Ну все языки не без греха. Спасибо вам большое :)